# Name of book trilogy with alternate dimension that looks like a more vibrant ancient Earth

Tags: story-identification

Ok, this has been bothering me for a few months. There is a book series (I believe it was a trilogy) that I read about 15 years ago and for the life of me I can’t remember the name or author.

The plot is that a guy in modern times climbs into an earthen mound one day and it ends up being a portal to a different dimension, that is similar to ancient Earth times but everything is much more vibrant (colors, sound, beautiful people) and it’s fantasy/sci-fi and the people drink mead a lot (fermented honey wine).

This is all I can remember. Ring a bell, anyone?

Comment: This very vaguely rings a bell, is it possible it was a child/ teenage audience book? I remember reading something very vaguely like it ten years ago or so. I'll try to remember more of it.

Comment: Thank you! This has been driving me insane for about 2 months